# UV-Vis spectrum of alkane

Tags: organic-chemistry, uv-vis-spectroscopy

My reference books stated:

> Methane's maximum absorption wavelength is 125 nm, ethane's is 135 nm. The longer the carbon chain, the larger the absorption wavelength, it is 165 nm for n-octane.

Well, I have tried to explain this based on organic chemistry, specifically hyperconjugation. However, it is still an unexplainable problem for me.

Comment: There is no simple explanation for this behavior.  Increasing $\lambda$ is not just predictable with increasing carbon number. For example, structure of the molecule plays a role too. Hope [this](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp903435c) would help you.

Comment: Yes, the paper helps. Since the question is mainly for hypothesis about interaction for linear alkane chain. I'll take other factors into account when it comes to more carbon atoms